# In PyQt6, I need to activate a subwindow after clicking it so that I can use the widget inside it

Tags: python, pyqt6

I am developing a chat app in python PyQt6. The chat window is a subwindow, I can create as many subwindows as I want. But my problem is, each time I create a second subwindow and go back to the first subwindow, it does not work anymore, I have identified that it is possible that the subwindow although got the focused, it is stiil not activated, is this correct? Or is there anything I am missing?

here is the full source:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
import mysql.connector as mysql
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


on_load = 0
on_start = 0
regr = 0
WS_y = 0
class MainW(QMainWindow):
    count = 0
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainW, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 800, 550)
        layout1 = QHBoxLayout()
        layout2 = QVBoxLayout()
        
        self.mdi = QMdiArea()
        
        widget = QWidget()
        
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)        
        
        self.frnlist = QListWidget(self)
        #
        #self.frnlist.setSize(90,self.height()/2)
        self.frnlist.resize(90, self.height()/2)
        #self.frnlist.setHeight(self.height()/2)
        self.frnlist.currentTextChanged.connect(self.text_changed)
        self.romlist = QListWidget(self)
        #
        self.romlist.resize(90, self.height()/2)
        #self.romlist.setHeight(90, self.height()/2)
        self.romlist.currentTextChanged.connect(self.text_changed)
        
        layout2.addWidget(self.frnlist)
        layout2.addWidget(self.romlist)
        layout1.addLayout( layout2 )
        layout1.addWidget(self.mdi, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop)
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout1)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        
        self.bar = self.menuBar()
        nMe = self.bar.addMenu("My Info")
        nMe.addAction("Profile")
        nMe.addAction("Timeline")
        nMe.addAction("Cluster")
        nMe.addSeparator()
        nMe.addAction("Logout")        
        nMe.triggered[QAction].connect(self.manage_me)
        
        nFriends = self.bar.addMenu("Friends")
        nFriends.addAction("Add")
        nFriends.addAction("Display")
        nFriends.addAction("Update")        
        nFriends.triggered[QAction].connect(self.manage_friends)
        nRooms = self.bar.addMenu("Rooms")
        nRooms.addAction("Add")
        nRooms.addAction("Display")
        nRooms.addAction("Update")        
        nRooms.triggered[QAction].connect(self.manage_rooms)
        nWins = self.bar.addMenu("Chats")
        nWins.addAction("Tile")
        nWins.addAction("Cascade")
        nWins.triggered[QAction].connect(self.wclick)
        nSyst = self.bar.addMenu("System")
        nSyst.addAction("Preferences")
        nSyst.addAction("Settings")
        nSyst.addAction("About Popchat")
        nSyst.addSeparator()
        nSyst.addAction("Quit")
        nSyst.triggered[QAction].connect(self.about)
        self.statusBar = QStatusBar()
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)
        self.statusBar.showMessage("Ready", 5000)
        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        timer.start(1000)
        self.lbl_tmr = QLabel()
        self.statusBar.addPermanentWidget(self.lbl_tmr)
        self.lbl_tmr.move(30, 40)
        self.bar.setEnabled(False)
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Pop Chat")
        
    def show_login(self):
        self.subl= QMdiSubWindow()
        lblusr =  QLabel('UserName', self.subl)
        lblusr.setStyleSheet('QLabel {background-color: transparent; color: black;}')
        lblusr.setGeometry(15, 45, 70, 30) 
        self.subl.txtusr = QLineEdit('', self.subl) 
        
        self.subl.txtusr.setGeometry(90, 45, 100, 30)  
        lblpwd =  QLabel('Password', self.subl)
        lblpwd.setStyleSheet('QLabel {background-color: transparent; color: black;}')
        lblpwd.setGeometry(15, 90, 70, 30) 
        self.subl.txtpwd = QLineEdit('', self.subl) 
        self.subl.txtusr.setPlaceholderText("Enter Username Here")
        self.subl.txtpwd.setPlaceholderText("Enter Password Here")
        self.subl.txtpwd.setGeometry(90, 90, 100, 30) 
        self.subl.txtpwd.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.EchoMode.Password)        
        self.subl.pblogin = QPushButton('Login', self.subl)
        #self.subl.pblogin.setEnabled(False)
        self.subl.pblogin.setGeometry(70, 160, 50, 20)
        self.subl.pblogin.clicked.connect(self.setLogin)
        self.subl.pbReg = QPushButton('Register', self.subl)
        #self.subl.pblogin.setEnabled(False)
        self.subl.pbReg.setGeometry(125, 160, 50, 20)
        self.subl.pbReg.clicked.connect(self.showReg)
        #self.subl.pblogin.clicked.connect(self.onClick_pb3)  
        #self.subl.txtpwd.textChanged.connect(self.on_text_changed)
        #self.subl.txtusr.textChanged.connect(self.on_text_changed)
        pbcanc = QPushButton('Cancel', self.subl)
        pbcanc.setGeometry(180, 160 , 50, 20)
        #pbcanc.clicked.connect(self.onClick_pb4)
        
        self.subl.setGeometry(65, 65,250, 200)
        self.subl.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
        #self.subl.move(45, 45)
        #self.subl.setWindowTitle("Login")
        self.mdi.addSubWindow(self.subl)
        self.subl.show()
    def wclick(self, q):                  
        if q.text() == "Cascade":
           self.mdi.cascadeSubWindows()
                    
        if q.text() == "Tile":
          self.mdi.tileSubWindows()  
          
        if q.text() == "Hide Documents Toolbar":
          self.toolbar.toggleViewAction().setChecked(True)
          self.toolbar.toggleViewAction().trigger() 
        if q.text() == "Unhide Documents Toolbar":
          self.toolbar.toggleViewAction().setChecked(False)
          self.toolbar.toggleViewAction().trigger()  
    def setLogin(self):
        global on_load
        self.frnlist.addItems(["One", "Two", "Three"])
        self.romlist.addItems(["One", "Two", "Three"])
        self.bar.setEnabled(True)
        on_load = 1
        self.subl.close()
    def showReg(self):
        global on_load, regr
        self.subl.close()
        regr = 1
        on_load = 1
    def setReg(self):
        global on_load
        
        self.regr= QMdiSubWindow()
        
        lblname =  QLabel('FullName', self.regr)
        lblname.setStyleSheet('QLabel {background-color: transparent; color: black;}')
        lblname.setGeometry(15, 45, 70, 30) 
        self.regr.txtname = QLineEdit('', self.regr) 
        self.regr.txtname.setGeometry(90, 45, 150, 30)
        self.regr.txtname.setPlaceholderText("Enter Fullname Here")
        
        lblmail =  QLabel('Email', self.regr)
        lblmail.setStyleSheet('QLabel {background-color: transparent; color: black;}')
        lblmail.setGeometry(15, 90, 70, 30) 
        self.regr.txtmail = QLineEdit('', self.regr) 
        
        self.regr.txtmail.setGeometry(90, 90, 150, 30)
        self.regr.txtmail.setPlaceholderText("Enter Email Here")
        
        
        lblusr =  QLabel('UserName', self.regr)
        lblusr.setStyleSheet('QLabel {background-color: transparent; color: black;}')
        lblusr.setGeometry(15, 135, 70, 30) 
        self.regr.txtusr = QLineEdit('', self.regr) 
        
        self.regr.txtusr.setGeometry(90, 135, 100, 30)

        
        
        lblpwd =  QLabel('Password', self.regr)
        lblpwd.setStyleSheet('QLabel {background-color: transparent; color: black;}')
        lblpwd.setGeometry(15, 180, 70, 30) 
        self.regr.txtpwd = QLineEdit('', self.regr) 
        self.regr.txtusr.setPlaceholderText("Enter Username Here")
        self.regr.txtpwd.setPlaceholderText("Enter Password Here")
        self.regr.txtpwd.setGeometry(90, 180, 100, 30) 
        self.regr.txtpwd.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.EchoMode.Password)

        lblpwd1 =  QLabel('Reenter Pwd', self.regr)
        lblpwd1.setStyleSheet('QLabel {background-color: transparent; color: black;}')
        lblpwd1.setGeometry(15, 225, 70, 30) 
        self.regr.txtpwd1 = QLineEdit('', self.regr) 
        
        self.regr.txtpwd1.setPlaceholderText("ReEnter Password Here")
        self.regr.txtpwd1.setGeometry(90, 225, 100, 30) 
        self.regr.txtpwd1.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.EchoMode.Password)

        
        on_load = 1
       
        self.regr.setGeometry(65, 65,270, 360)
        self.regr.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.mdi.addSubWindow(self.regr)
        
        self.regr.show()
    def about(self, s):
        aboutm = QMessageBox()
        aboutm.setIcon(QMessageBox.Icon.Information)
        aboutm.setWindowTitle('Software Information')
        aboutm.setStyleSheet('QLabel {background-color: transparent; color: black;}')
        aboutm.setText("Title: Popchat \n Version: 1.00 \n Release Date: June 6, 2022")
        aboutm.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok)
        aboutm = aboutm.exec()
        
    def showTime(self):
        global on_start, regr
        if on_start == 0:
           self.show_login()
        current_time = QTime.currentTime()  
        label_time = current_time.toString('hh:mm:ss')
        self.lbl_tmr.setText(label_time) 
        on_start = 1
        if regr == 1:
            regr = 0
            self.setReg()
    def manage_me(self, q):       
        if q.text() == "New":
            MainW.count = MainW.count + 1
            sub = QMdiSubWindow()
            redb = QPushButton('Horizontal', sub)
            redb.setCheckable(True)
            redb.setGeometry(20, 30, 80, 20)           
            sub.setGeometry(25, 25, 250, 150)
            sub.setWindowTitle("subwindow" + str(MainW.count))
            self.mdi.addSubWindow(sub)
            sub.show()
            
    def manage_friends(self, q):       
        if q.text() == "New":
            MainW.count = MainW.count + 1
            sub = QMdiSubWindow()
            redb = QPushButton('Horizontal', sub)
            redb.setCheckable(True)
            redb.setGeometry(20, 30, 80, 20)           
            sub.setGeometry(25, 25, 250, 150)
            sub.setWindowTitle("subwindow" + str(MainW.count))
            self.mdi.addSubWindow(sub)
            sub.show()
    def manage_rooms(self, q):       
        if q.text() == "New":
            MainW.count = MainW.count + 1
            sub = QMdiSubWindow()
            redb = QPushButton('Horizontal', sub)
            redb.setCheckable(True)
            redb.setGeometry(20, 30, 80, 20)           
            sub.setGeometry(5, 5, 250, 300)
            sub.setWindowTitle("subwindow" + str(MainW.count))
            self.mdi.addSubWindow(sub)
            sub.show()
            
    def sSend(self):
        global WS_y
        
        self.sub.y(WS_y).etext.append(self.sub.y(WS_y).lineedit.text())
        self.sub.y(WS_y).lineedit.setText("")
        
    def text_changed(self, s): # s is a str
        global on_load
        #print(MainW)
        if on_load == 1:
          self.sub = QMdiSubWindow()
          #sub.setLayout(QFormLayout())
          self.sub.y = 1
          print(self.sub.y)
          WS_y = self.sub.y
          #redb = QPushButton('Horizontal', sub)
          #redb.setCheckable(True)
          #redb.setGeometry(20, 30, 80, 20)           
          # construct the top level widget
          formLayout = QFormLayout()
          
          widget = QWidget()
          # construct the top level layout
          layout = QHBoxLayout(widget)
          cGroup = QGroupBox()
          cGroup.setLayout(layout)
          # create the widgets to add to the layout
          self.sub.etext = QTextEdit()
          self.sub.etext.setEnabled(False)
          lbl =  QLabel('')
          self.sub.lineedit = QLineEdit()
          pbsend = QPushButton('>>', clicked=self.sSend)
          #pbsend.clicked.connect(self.sSend('a1'))
          formLayout.layout().addRow(self.sub.etext)
          formLayout.layout().addRow(cGroup)
          #formLayout.layout().addRow(layouth)
          # add the widgets to the layout
          
          layout.addWidget(self.sub.lineedit)
          layout.addWidget(pbsend)
          
          #layout.addWidget(layouth)
          # set the layout on the widget
          widget.setLayout(formLayout)
          # we now have a single widget that contains a layout and 2 widgets
          self.sub.setWidget(widget)
          self.sub.setGeometry(5, 5, 250, 300)
          self.sub.setWindowTitle(s)
          self.mdi.addSubWindow(self.sub)
          self.sub.show()
        on_load = 1
        s = ''
        
def main():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = MainW()
   ex.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec())
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

I could not find a solution yet, but I am looking at setActiveSubWindow() as a possible solution.

Answer (score -3):

I already found a solution to my problem.
Here is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QMdiArea, 
QMdiSubWindow, QTextEdit, QLineEdit, QHBoxLayout, 
QVBoxLayout, 
QPushButton, QWidget)


class ChatWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChatWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.text_edit = QTextEdit()
        self.text_edit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.text_edit.setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit.NoWrap)
        self.text_edit.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        self.text_edit.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.NoTextInteraction)
        self.line_edit = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit.setPlaceholderText("Enter message here")
        self.send_button = QPushButton("Send")
        self.send_button.clicked.connect(self.send_message)

    # Layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)
        h_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        h_layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        h_layout.addWidget(self.send_button)
        layout.addLayout(h_layout)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def send_message(self):
        message = self.line_edit.text()
        if message:
            self.text_edit.append(message)
            self.line_edit.clear()
    

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

mdi = QMdiArea()

num_of_chat_windows = 3
for i in range(num_of_chat_windows):
    sub_window = QMdiSubWindow()
    sub_window.setWidget(ChatWindow())
    sub_window.setWindowTitle("Chat {}".format(i+1))
    mdi.addSubWindow(sub_window)

main_window = QMainWindow()
main_window.setCentralWidget(mdi)
main_window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks to chatgpt he was able to solve it